# System error 1722. The RPC server is unavailable. When calling net user

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm using the windows command *net user user id /domain* to check the groups for windows ids. When i make the call I get the error system error 1722

```
C:\folder\net user userid /domain

The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain XXX.YYY.

System error 1722 has occurred.

The RPC server is unavailable.
```

Where / how can this issue to be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP in advanced TCP/IP Settings

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me.